# Is there any chance to play Gwent again with the guy in White Orchard?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Apparently, there was some kind of bug playing Gwent against the first guy you meet in White Orchard, the historian in the inn where you first go with Vesemir. Every time I passed, the the game crashed (PS4 disc copy) so I skipped that and tried to played again Gwent later in the game when I went to Velen. I since went back to white orchard hoping to challenge that guy again but I failed to find him again.

Is there a way to play against him somewhere else? If you beat him, does he give away a card?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can play him again. But don't worry, his card is non-unique one. So if you're looking for the achievement it doesn't actually require you to get ALL cards, just the 120 unique ones ;)

Source: http://www.trueachievements.com/a200110/card-collector-achievement.htm

Answer (score 0):

Once you leave White Orchard, that NPC is no longer available.

However, he does reward you with a card if you beat him. Patch 1.0.7 made it so that if you fail to beat or talk to him after leaving White Orchard for the first time, you can find the card you are supposed to win from him under the Hanged Man's Tree in Velen.